# Can extracting a base class break binary serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, binary-serialization

If I have a class with a number of fields, and I serialise it using binary serialisation.

I then extract a base class and move some of the fields from the class into the base class. Eg.

```
class Class
{
     int field1;
     string field2;
}
```

Is changed to

```
class Class : BaseClass
{
     int field1;
}

class BaseClass
{
     string field2;
}
```

Is it possible for this to break serialisation in any way - i.e. will it always be possible to deserialise old versions of Class into new versions of Class and vice versa.

Experiments I performed indicated that this is fine, but if somebody knows of any edge cases where this wouldn't work, that would obviously be great before I put this into production code.

Comment: BinaryFormatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
There is a problem while deserializing: the member "field1" will not be properly deserialized.

1) Serialized person:

```
var person = new Employee()
            { 
                Name = "Mark Zuckerberg",
                Salary = 1000
            };

var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(new FileStream("C:\\TEMP\\test.dat", FileMode.Create), person);


[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

2) Changed class structure

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }           
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee : Person
{            
  public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

3) Deserialized: Name is null
[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

Assuming you are using the [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) article does not mention anything about it, so I **guess** it's fine (**EDIT: It's NOT fine**).

Here are some best practices to follow generally (also extracted from above article):

- Never remove a serialized field.
- Never apply the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to a field if the
  attribute was not applied to the field in the previous version.
- Never change the name or the type of a serialized field.
- When adding a new serialized field, apply the OptionalFieldAttribute
  attribute.
- When removing a NonSerializedAttribute attribute from a field (that
  was not serializable in a previous version), apply the
  OptionalFieldAttribute attribute.
- For all optional fields, set meaningful defaults using the
  serialization callbacks unless 0 or null as defaults are acceptable.

To ensure that a type will be compatible with future serialization engines, follow these guidelines:

- Always set the VersionAdded property on the OptionalFieldAttribute
  attribute correctly.
- Avoid branched versioning.

Comment: Hmmm.Can you think of any way to fix that problem?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Not a proper solution, I'm afraid. The obvious option which comes into my mind is maintaining the old model until the data has been migrated and then discard it.In your deserializing code you could check if Name is null, use the old Model to deserialize and then assign that object to the new one.